# Unity Jumping issue for 3d fps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to create a movement script for a fps game. I have the movement working but the jump function is not working I am not sure whether the problem is with the code or the way I have the character set up. In the debug log, it is registering that I pressed the space key, In the debug it says: `FixedUpdate Jump UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object) PlayerMovement:FixedUpdate () (at Assets/PlayerMovement.cs:94)`

Here is the Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
     [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
 public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _speed = 7f;
    private CharacterController _charController;
    private float _mouseSensitivity = 450;
    private Camera _camera;
    private float xRotation = 0f;
    private float _minCameraview = -70f, _maxCameraview = 90f;
    private Vector3 _PlayerVelocity;
    public Vector3 jump;
    
public float jumpForce = 2.0f;
    bool isJumpPressed = false;
    public bool isGrounded = true;
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
      _camera = Camera.main;

      Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
      jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);

      //if(_charController == null)

        //Debug.log("No Character Controller attached to player"); 

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

      //Get WASD input for player
      float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
      // Move player based on WASD input
      Vector3 movement = transform.forward * vertical + transform.right * horizontal;
      
      _charController.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime * _speed);
    
      //Get mouse position input
      float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
      float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;


      // rotate camera based off Y input from Mouse
      xRotation -= mouseY;

      // Clamp Camera rotation
      xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, _minCameraview, _maxCameraview);


      _camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);

      // rotate player based off X input from Mouse
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX * 3);
      //Jumping 

      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded){
      
        rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
              }
    isJumpPressed = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
    if (isJumpPressed)
    {            
        Debug.Log("Update Jump");
    }
    }
void FixedUpdate()
       {
      // dectect if player is grounded 
        if (_charController.isGrounded)
        {
          _PlayerVelocity.y = 0f;

        }
          // apply gravity to player
        else
        {
            _PlayerVelocity.y += -9.18f * Time.deltaTime;
            _charController.Move(_PlayerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (isJumpPressed)
        {
          Debug.Log("FixedUpdate Jump");            
        }
       }

}
```

[Rigidbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTLVh.png)
I am also using the Rigidbody3D which I am new to as well, so here is how it is set up.

Here is the character controller [Character Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge9CH.png)

Here is the Player Movement in unity [PlayerMovement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YewQm.png)

So what am I doing wrong so my character won't jump? If possible could you explain because I am trying to understand the concepts behind it as well. (I am Using unity 2020.2.2f1 if that matters.)

Comment: If you say that you are using rigidbody and CharacterController, then that could definitely be the problem. You should never have both. There is always a way to do it without the other.

Comment: I have a simple script for you if you want to jump with character controller. Tell me if you would like it.

Comment: @ ken How would you go about only using the Rigidbody then? And if you could send me the script for the character controller as well that would be great because I would like to learn that as well.

Comment: Character controller is the better choice in this case. I will explain it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should never use both ChracacterController and Rigidbody. The reason for this is that it gets messy, it does two different physics calculations, and you can do it with either of them by themselves.

**When should I use Rigidbodies?**

Rigidbodies should be used in 2d games (as of now, there is no build in character controller for 2d). In 3D, you have a choice of Rigidbody or CharacterController. Rigidbody should be used for planes, boats, etc. And for any physics involved players. For non-player usage, Rigidbodies should be use for anything like a bullet or ball. Any object using physics.

**When should I use CharacterController?**

Character controllers should be used for players, and not heavily physics-involved objects like planes or boats. CharacterController has special built in features that allow it to climb up slopes with a certain slope limit. They also have step heights which can control how high the player can go up a 90° face (like the stairs).

---

I hear that the movement works fine, and you only want the jump to work. In this case, I will use CharacterController for the jumping.

```cs
float currentGravity;
Vector3 velocity;
public float jump = 2f;
public float gravity = -9.81f;
public float groundDist = 0.5f;
public LayerMask groundMask;

void Update()
{
   if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, groundedDist, groundedMask)
   {
       currentGravity = -0.5f; //to go slowly down because the player is not truly grounded.

       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
       {
           velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jump * -2 * gravity);
       }
   }
   else
   {
      currentGravity += gravity;
   }
   velocity.y += currentGravity;
   GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(velocity);
}
```

This is a script (untested) I made to add a jump. Basically, I raycast downward (line 10) with a max distance of *groundDist*. If the player is close enough to the ground, it will go slowly down just to hit the ground (line 12). In the same if statement, I detect if the player presses the jump key (line 14), and then I add jump to the player (line 16) with a physics equation written by [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE). Then, if the player isn’t on the ground (line 19: uses an *else* from the raycast if statement), it will gradually increase the gravity (line 21). Line 23: actually apply the gravity to the jump velocity (if the player jumped). And finally, line 24: I use *Move* to move the character downward by the velocity.

---

You should be able to add this to your script, but if you need help, reply to this, and I will add it. Let me know if you see/get any bugs/errors, and I will do my best to fix them.

**Links:**

- [Rigidbody or CharacterController?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1355011/difference-between-character-controller-and-rigidb.html)
- [Brackeys character controller tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE)

Comment: Something I didn’t add, but do it before you tell me you get an error for this reason: the ground isn’t being detected unless you add a *LayerMask* to the ground objects that is a certain name. Then make sure that same LayerMask is what the *groundMask* is set to.

Comment: So far I have fixed most of the compile errors but I am stuck on `Component.GetComponent<CharacterController>.Move(velocity);` I keep getting the error `Component.GetComponent<T>()' is a method, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: What should I do @ken?

Comment: Sorry, you are missing the () at the end of the > and before the .Move

Comment: Alright I hope this is the last thing, in `Component.GetComponent<CharacterController()> .Move(velocity);` In now get `Invalid expression term '.'` I though I could just remove the period but that Brough up a lot more errors, what is causing this?

Comment: I guess it should be: `GetComponent<CharacterController>() .Move(velocity);` be careful where you put the `()`